# Vue JS - How to hide an element when clicked outside of an element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, show-hide

I have four pictures when the user hovers over the picture, a certain element is displayed, and when the cursor is removed outside the element, the element disappears

In the mobile version, `mouseover` and `mouseleave` do not work, they are replaced naturally by clicks, but the problem is that when the user clicks outside the element, the element does not disappear, I tried different packages, but they do not work more precisely, the `v-click-outside` event does not work

You can see [my code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-knuth-yyg97)

After you open my project in codesandbox Open the page in a new tab by clicking on the "Open in new window" button then select the mobile version then click on the pictures after clicking again outside the element the element does not disappear

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="enjoy_headline_container">
      <div class="EnjoyGirlsContainer">
        <div>
          <h3 style="margin: 0">
            Open the page in a new tab by clicking on the "Open in new window"
            button then select the mobile version then click on the pictures
            after a second click outside the element the element does not
            disappear
          </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="EnjoyGirlsList">
          <div
            v-for="(chunk, index) in Math.ceil(EnjoyGirlsList.length / 2)"
            :key="'chunk-' + index"
            :class="'wrap-' + index"
          >
            <div
              v-for="(item, index) in EnjoyGirlsList.slice(
                (chunk - 1) * 2,
                chunk * 2
              )"
              :key="'img-' + index"
              class="EnjoyCard"
              :class="'EnjoyCard-' + index"
            >
              <div>
                <img
                  @mouseover="mouseOver(item, (hover = true))"
                  :src="item.imagePath"
                  alt="Snow"
                />
              </div>

              <div class="EnjoyCardContainer">
                <div
                  :style="{ background: item.textColor }"
                  class="EnjoyCardChildContainer"
                >
                  <h3 class="EnjoyCardChildContainerTitleName">
                    {{ item.titleName }}
                  </h3>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div
                v-if="selected === item"
                class="below-all-description EnjoyGirlsHoverEffect"
              >
                <div class="next-to-description EnjoyGirlsHoverEffect">
                  <div
                    style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center"
                    v-for="(enjoy, index) in EnjoyGirlsList"
                    :key="index"
                  >
                    <div
                      @mouseleave="mouseout(enjoy, (hover = false))"
                      class="EnjoyGirlsChildHoverEffect"
                    >
                      <component
                        v-show="enjoy.hovered"
                        v-bind:is="enjoy.componentName"
                      ></component>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="below-all-description">
          <template v-if="selected === null"></template>
          <template v-else>
            <div
              style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center"
              v-for="(enjoy, index) in EnjoyGirlsList"
              :key="index"
            >
              <div
                @mouseleave="mouseout(enjoy, (hover = false))"
                class="EnjoyGirlsChildHoverEffect"
              >
                <component
                  v-show="enjoy.hovered"
                  v-bind:is="enjoy.componentName"
                ></component>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EnjoyBlue from "./components/EnjoyBlue";
import EnjoyGreen from "./components/EnjoyGreen";
import EnjoyYellow from "./components/EnjoyYellow";
import EnjoyRed from "./components/EnjoyRed";

export default {
  name: "HomePage",
  components: {
    EnjoyRed,
    EnjoyYellow,
    EnjoyGreen,
    EnjoyBlue,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      hover: false,
      sectionGirlsListComponentsNames: [
        "EnjoyRed",
        "EnjoyYellow",
        "EnjoyGreen",
        "EnjoyBlue",
      ],
      EnjoyGirlsList: [
        {
          imagePath: "https://i.ibb.co/mCpNXhG/IMG-6061-min.png",
          titleName: "TEENS",
          textColor: "#74C8C5",
          hovered: false,
          componentName: "EnjoyBlue",
        },
        {
          imagePath: "https://i.ibb.co/WvJjwsN/Rectangle-2.png",
          titleName: "MINXES",
          textColor: "#76ED00",
          hovered: false,
          componentName: "EnjoyGreen",
        },
        {
          imagePath: "https://i.ibb.co/7khc5f0/Rectangle-3.png",
          titleName: "MILFS",
          textColor: "#FFE600",
          hovered: false,
          componentName: "EnjoyYellow",
        },
        {
          imagePath: "https://i.ibb.co/6nz97Bw/Rectangle-4.png",
          titleName: "COURGARS",
          textColor: "#CC003D",
          hovered: false,
          componentName: "EnjoyRed",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    mouseOver: function (enjoy) {
      this.EnjoyGirlsList.forEach((enjoy) => (enjoy.hovered = false));
      this.selected = enjoy;
      enjoy.hovered = true;
      if (this.hover) {
        console.log("4949494");
      }
    },
    mouseout: function (enjoy) {
      this.selected = null;
      enjoy.hovered = false;
    },
    mouseEnter: function () {},
    Prev() {
      this.$refs.carousel.prev();
    },
    showNext() {
      this.$refs.carousel.next();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: When you show the item - add event listener for `click` events to `document`, when you hide the item - remove this event listener. The event listener function will check `if (!(popupItem.contains(event.target) || event.target === popupItem)) this.hidePopup();`

Comment: Please show me some example code in codesandbox which I left a link on my question

Comment: Try https://codesandbox.io/s/great-firefly-7n0up